# FlexSlider 2 w/thumbnail slider - Prev Next for Main Image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, flexslider

I am using FlexSlider 2 with the thumbnail slider. However, the problem is, that the mainimage isn't responsing. If I press the next/prev buttons, it won't slide/fade to the next/prev image. Even if I click on one of the thumbnails, it won't change. But the prev/next buttons of thumbnail slider works fine. I just can't find the problem. I didn't touch the **flexslider.js**, but the **flexslider.css**. I changed some things to get rid of the bordershadow and so on. But I used also the untouched **flexslider.css** and it didn't work too. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow: false,
        touch: true,
        itemWidth: 160,
        itemMargin: 3,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
      });

      $('#slider').flexslider({
        start: function(slider) {
          $('html').removeClass('no-js');
          slider.removeClass('loading');
        },
        animation: "fade",
        slideshow: false,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: true,
        touch: true,
        useCSS: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 3000,
        animationSpeed: 300,
        sync: "#carousel"

      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    function launchFullScreen(element) {
      if (element.requestFullscreen) {
        element.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
        element.msRequestFullscreen();
      }
      $('.slide_text').css('bottom', '5%');
      $('.slide_text').css('zoom', '1.5');
      $('.flex-fullscreen-launch').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $('.flex-fullscreen-cancel').css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('.flex-fullscreen-cancel').css('top', '20%');
      $('.flex-play-button').css('top', '20%');
      $('.flex-pause-button').css('top', '20%');
      $('.flex-next-button').css('bottom', '30%');
      $('.flex-prev-button').css('bottom', '30%');
      $('.flex-control-thumbs').css('position', 'static');
    }

    function cancelFullScreen() {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
      $('.slide_text').css('bottom', '2%');
      $('.slide_text').css('zoom', '1');
      $('.flex-fullscreen-launch').css('visibility', 'visible');
      $('.flex-fullscreen-cancel').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $('.flex-fullscreen-launch').css('top', '6%');
      $('.flex-play-button').css('top', '6%');
      $('.flex-pause-button').css('top', '6%');
      $('.flex-next-button').css('bottom', '54%');
      $('.flex-prev-button').css('bottom', '54%');
      $('.flex-control-thumbs').css('position', 'absolute');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="div_left">
      <input class="button active" type="button" value="Button 1" />
      <input class="button" type="button" value="Button 2" />
      <input class="button" type="button" value="Button 3" />
      <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/1.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/2.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/3.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/4.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/5.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/6.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/7.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/8.jpg" />
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="flex-fullscreen-launch" href="#" onclick="launchFullScreen(document.getElementById('slider'))"></a>
        <a class="flex-fullscreen-cancel" href="#" onclick="cancelFullScreen(document.getElementById('slider'))"></a>
        <a class="flex-play-button" href="#" onclick="$('#carousel').flexslider('play'); $('.flex-play-button').css('visibility', 'hidden'); $('.flex-pause-button').css('visibility', 'visible');"></a>
        <a class="flex-pause-button" href="#" onclick="$('#carousel').flexslider('pause'); $('.flex-pause-button').css('visibility', 'hidden'); $('.flex-play-button').css('visibility', 'visible');"></a>
        <a class="flex-next-button" href="#" onclick="$('#slider').flexslider('next');"></a>
        <a class="flex-prev-button" href="#" onclick="$('#slider').flexslider('prev');"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/1-small.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/2-small.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/3-small.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/4-small.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/5-small.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/6-small.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/7-small.jpg" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <img alt="asdf" src="img/8-small.jpg" />
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="flex-next-button" href="#" onclick="$('#carousel').flexslider('next');"></a>
        <a class="flex-prev-button" href="#" onclick="$('#carousel').flexslider('prev');"></a>
      </div>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this jsFiddle it works

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r59c2z7/2/)

```
Hope this helps
```

Comment: Strange. It works on me too, but if I use it with localhost, it doesn't work. You didn't change anything, right?

Comment: All i changed were the images. for the buttons i put some text in them so that i could see them

Comment: Hey servinIp!

You helped me a lot. Because of you, I realized my mistake. I used an incorrect jQuery File. I downloaded the newest and now it works perfectly.

Comment: The jsFiddle FullScreen Code doesn't work on mobile. Iphone and Android tested. Can you help?

Comment: It's not supported on a lot of mobile browsers.